# Let $S$ be the set of all cauchy sequences.Does the set countable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all Cauchy sequences.Does the set countable?

Can we define a mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $S$ such that $f(n)$$=$$a_{m_n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ where $a_{m_1}$,$a_{m_2}$, . . are Cauchy sequences and from that can we say that the set $S$ is countable ?

Comment: Do you mean real sequences, being Cauchy in the Euclidean metric?

Comment: "Does the set countable?" Of course not. That would mean that $\mathbb R$ is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of Cauchy sequences of shape $(a_n)$ where $a_n=\frac{\delta_n}{2^n}$,  and each $\delta_n$ is $0$ or $1$, or if you prefer, $-1$ or $1$. This set already has the cardinality of the continuum, so is in particular uncountable. It follows that the set of Cauchy sequences of **rationals** is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

The irrational numbers are limits of sequences of rational numbers. These sequences must be Cauchy since they converge in $\mathbb{R}$, but the irrational numbers are uncountable therefore the set of all Cauchy sequences must be uncountable.